# Problem with AdWidget in Flutter Dart (AdWidget requires Ad.load to be called before...)

Tags: flutter, dart, admob

I get the error in the picture from the code that follows.

The app is useing WordPress REST API to get titles and pics from a wp site.
Then puts them in Cards. All works as intended until I try to show an ad in bottomNavigationBar...

I think the problem is that I'm trying to put the ad in FutureBuilder. But can't figure it out.

Any thoughts?

[AdWidget requires Ad.load to be called before AdWidget is inserted into the tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yzmB.png)

```
// @dart=2.9
// this downgrade is necessary because of the damn null safety

import...

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final initFuture = MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  final adState = AdState(initFuture);

  runApp(
    Provider.value(value: adState, builder: (context, child) => MyApp()),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.yellow),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

// some code...

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  BannerAd banner;
  bool _bannerIsLoaded = false;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    final adState = Provider.of<AdState>(context);
    adState.initialization.then((status) {
      setState(() {
        banner = BannerAd(
            size: AdSize.banner,
            adUnitId: adState.bannerAdUnitId,
            listener: BannerAdListener(onAdLoaded: (Ad ad) {
              print('$BannerAd loaded.');
              setState(() {
                _bannerIsLoaded = true;
              });
            }),
            request: AdRequest());
        banner.load();
      });
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

// some code...

            ),
          ])),
      body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
                child: FutureBuilder(
                    future: fetchWpPosts(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
                        return ListView.builder(

                          // some code...

                                        ])));
                          },
                        );
                      }

                      return Container(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          child: Center(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(strokeWidth: 5.0),
                          ));
                    }))
          ]),
      bottomNavigationBar: _bannerIsLoaded
          ? SizedBox(height: 50, child: AdWidget(ad: banner))
          : SizedBox(height: 50),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you later find a solution for this problem?.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I outsourced the whole project and haven't looked at the new code.